# AllItems.aspx in Shared Documents folder not showing all items until "Next Page", "Previous Page", "Next Page" is pressed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have several folders in our Shared Documents library that have over 100 documents. When initially opening these folders, the library shows that are less than 60 documents in the folder. In order to see all of the documents in the folder, we have to press the "Next Page" button to get to the second page (we still have the 30 item per page default set), press the "Previous Page" button to navigate back to the initial 30 items in the folder then press the "Next Page" button again. At that point we can see all of the documents in the folder. This issue is also happening in the MS SharePoint Workspace software on the desktop.

Looking through the library settings, I have been unable to find any setting that might be causing this. I tried to increase the Item Limit to 60, but that did not correct the issue. Has anyone seen this behavior before and/or have any advice as to how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is by default, too many items in a list view at once can impact performance for other people, and paging through more than 30-60 items on a page gets unwieldy for most end users. The higher the count of items, the longer the list will take to display. User Focus groups showed what works for most people, so that is the count that is set by default. Also, if no limit is set, you could exceed the threshold of 3000 (or is it 5000 now?) items and then you'll get warnings and no results will show until the view is changed.

You can try setting the Group By number higher, that may impact the number in the folders view. I think the only way to change the default for folders is to create a custom view in SharePoint Designer.

Although a lot of people use folders, adding columns and filtering/grouping by them may be another option to look at as you can control the counts displayed there a bit easier.

If there are so many items and people cannot find what they are looking for, try Creating a New View for the Library:

- Z-A based on Created or Modified date, than people will see the newest items on the top of the list.
- add additional columns to the library such as a list of department or project names, and create a view using the Group By or Filter option using that category.
- A view that is filtered where Created by is equal to [Me] then
  people will be able to see their own items.

You can also show your end users how to use the Search feature for that library, or sort and filter by the columns to find the documents they need.